# Quotes stripped gnu make $(if ...) argument

Tags: macros, makefile, arguments, quotes, strip

What are the rules in GNU make regarding quote characters?  I had thought that in most cases they would simply be part of the text in the make file and usually have no special meaning to make.  The following simple make file demonstrates that double quote characters appearing around an argument to $(if ...) are being stripped rather than passed out of the $(if) call.  This seems wrong, and oddly the unescaped quotes do pass through in a more complex make file I've been using.

```
include gmsl

VAR1  ?= var1_value
VAR2  ?= var2_value1 var2_value2

failquote = $(if $(call ne,$(words $(1)),1),"$(1)",$(1))
passquote = $(if $(call ne,$(words $(1)),1),\"$(1)\",$(1))

TESTFAILQUOTE = $(call failquote,$(VAR2))
TESTPASSQUOTE = $(call passquote,$(VAR2))

quotetest :
    @echo "--->Executing recipe for quotetest"
    @echo VAR2 is $(VAR2)
    @echo TESTFAILQUOTE = $(TESTFAILQUOTE)
    @echo TESTPASSQUOTE = $(TESTPASSQUOTE)
```

The output is thus:

```
bash-4.1$ make -f test_quote.mk quotetest
--->Executing recipe for quotetest
TESTFAILQUOTE = var2_value1 var2_value2
TESTPASSQUOTE = "var2_value1 var2_value2"
```

Note: you'll need the Gnu Make Standard library for this make file to work, for the $(call ne,...).  Find it here: http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What is the actual issue here? Is that output incorrect somehow? Is MadScientist right and the problem here is just the output missing quotes because the shell is stripping them?

Comment: The issue is that I need the literal quote characters in the output.  MadScientist is both sharp and very gracious with his/her help, and correct - if the quotes need to make it to the 'echo' command, they need to be escaped in the make variable value.

Comment: No, escaping them in the variable value is not the answer. The answer is quoting the variable expansion on the shell line so the shell doesn't strip them.

Comment: For the record the inclusion of gmsl, etc. here just *greatly* confused the issue as far as I'm concerned and should have been left out entirely.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Actually it is the answer, because the shell in question is actually $(shell ...), so I don't have the opportunity to escape there.  I left that part out to unconfuse the issue, and as you point out I should have left out the gmsl usage for the same reason.

Comment: `$(shell)` just calls `SHELL` which defaults to `/bin/sh` which, like on recipe lines, removes quotes as part of processing lines. I should have been more clear. Escaping the quotes is a correct solution to having the shell not swallow them. However, that is only one possible problem with variable expansions in shell contexts, others include word-splitting and shell globbing, and escaped quotes do not help those other cases. Single quoting the expansion, however, protects against the shell doing *anything* with the variables contents (short of the variable containing a single quote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding.  Make never strips quotes.  However, make invokes the shell and the shell will strip quotes.

If you remove the `@` tokens at the beginning of your `echo` lines you'll see how make is invoking the shell; you'll see:

```
echo TESTFAILQUOTE = "var2_value1 var2_value2"
var2_value1 var2_value2
echo TESTPASSQUOTE = \"var2_value1 var2_value2\"
"var2_value1 var2_value2"
```

If you run those same echo commands at your shell prompt you'll get the same results, showing that none of this is related to make.

Comment: Thanks, you are exactly correct.  I was just about to answer it myself but you are quicker than me!  I would upvote the answer but don't have enough cred yet.

Comment: Single quote make variable expansions used on shell command lines the same way you double quote shell variable expansions in normal circumstances. You need to prevent the normal shell expansions/etc. from happening.